# How to loop through JSON object with $.each JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to make a live search with JSON data from [star wars api](http://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json). The JSON contain of some `objects`, and the `objects` I wanted to fetch is `results`, which is an `array` that contains `objects` that have propertie `name`,`height`,`mass`, ect.

The snippet of the JSON like this:

```
    {
    "count": 87,
    "next": "http://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json&page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
    {
    "name": "Luke Skywalker",
    "height": "172",
    "mass": "77",
    "hair_color": "blond",
    "skin_color": "fair",
    "eye_color": "blue",
    "birth_year": "19BBY",
    "gender": "male",
    "homeworld": "http://swapi.co/api/planets/1/",
    "films": [
    "http://swapi.co/api/films/6/",
    "http://swapi.co/api/films/3/",
    "http://swapi.co/api/films/2/",
    "http://swapi.co/api/films/1/",
    "http://swapi.co/api/films/7/"
    ],
    "species": [
    "http://swapi.co/api/species/1/"
    ],
    "vehicles": [
    "http://swapi.co/api/vehicles/14/",
    "http://swapi.co/api/vehicles/30/"
    ],
    "starships": [
    "http://swapi.co/api/starships/12/",
    "http://swapi.co/api/starships/22/"
    ],
    "created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z",
    "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z",
    "url": "http://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
    }
]
}
```

I tried with this code but the console says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` (on line 7)

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    $.getJSON('http://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json', function(data) {
        var output = '<ul class="searchresults">';
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            if ((val.results.name.search(myExp) != -1) ||
            (val.results.height.search(myExp) != -1)) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<h2>'+ val.name +'</h2>';
                output += '<p>'+ val.height +'</p>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('#update').html(output);
    });
});
```

I know there's something wrong with my loop, I tried looking for the the answer but I can't get the right answer. Can you please help me?

Comment: `Val` in `undefined`, thus `val.name` does not work. Have you verified that the endpoint give you well formatted json?

Comment: results is array and not object property you must iterate results to acess name

Comment: @Akshaypadwal yeah, I said `results` is array that contain objects

Comment: then you must iterate as i show below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple mistake, you should iterate over data.results

```
$.getJSON('http://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.results, function(key, val) { 
    console.log(val.name); 
    })
});
```

Your JSON contains :

- "count": 87,
- "next": "http://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json&page=2",
- "previous": null,
- "results": **The data you want**

So you must get results and iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the `results` of the `data` object like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json', function(data) {
  $.each(data.results, function(key, value){
    console.log("key", key); 
    console.log("value", value.name)
   })
})
```

Or in your case:

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    $.getJSON('http://swapi.co/api/people/?format=json', function(data) {
        var output = '<ul class="searchresults">';
        $.each(data.results, function(key, val) { //Only this line changes.
            if ((val.results.name.search(myExp) != -1) ||
            (val.results.height.search(myExp) != -1)) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<h2>'+ val.name +'</h2>';
                output += '<p>'+ val.height +'</p>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('#update').html(output);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have something like:

```
output += '<h2>'+ val.results.name +'</h2>';
output += '<p>'+ val.results.height +'</p>';
```

exactly as you have in your `if` condition

Answer (score 0):

Make your `$.each` loop as below:Because `val.results` is in array format of json.

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
        var results = val.results;
        $.each(results,function(index,value){
            if ((value[index].name.search(myExp) != -1) ||
            (value[index].height.search(myExp) != -1)) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<h2>'+ value[index].name +'</h2>';
                output += '<p>'+ value[index].height +'</p>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });

        });
```

Hope it will works correctly.

OR simply

```
        $.each(data.results,function(index,value){
            if ((value[index].name.search(myExp) != -1) ||
            (value[index].height.search(myExp) != -1)) {
                output += '<li>';
                output += '<h2>'+ value[index].name +'</h2>';
                output += '<p>'+ value[index].height +'</p>';
                output += '</li>';
            }
        });
```

May be enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
var a = //your json;

$.each(a,function(i,val){
if(val.results.length != 0){
$.each(val.results,function(k,value){
console.log(value.name)})
}
})
```